# separate login section for admin and normal website user in cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 1.3.14 to develop a website. I need to create separate login section/screen for admin and normal website user. I don't want to use same login section for all the users as per my requirements. Admin should have a separate login screen. I need some help with this. How can I implement it in cakephp. Thanks in advance.

Comment: erm.... what is the problem? do you wanna use different tables for users and administrators or just different forms?

Comment: my main objective is to show different forms. Currently I have separate tables for admin and user. But I can use same table also if I get separate forms. Normal users login from home page and I want to create separate page for admin login.

Comment: well if I were you I use the same table for both users and admins, I put form in the file view/forms/login.ctp,
than I use this file on the differet pages, if user logged in I redirect him to home page etc, if admin sign in I redirect him to admin side. Something like this, sorry for my english, hope you will understand me

Comment: Do as @sukinsan said - simply redirect the user to the admin section of the site if they are a member of the admin group. Use prefix routing to make your life easier :)

Comment: @sukinsan thanks, I got your point. I'll try your idea and see if I am able to implement it.
If I face problem with this, I'll get back to you guys.

Comment: Oh yes, it's very important, use prefix routing as @Barry Chapman said

Answer (score 1):

You should use [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#index-2) so that regular users will see /controller/action and admins get their own prefix like /admin/controller/action.

Simply create an admin action and internally "redirect" the controller to use the regular login action. No need to duplicate code. See http://api20.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllersetAction

```
public function admin_login() {
    $this->layout = 'admin_login';
    $this->setAction('login');
}
```

To get another layout for the admin you can check in the beforeFilter() if the prefix is "admin" and set a different layout based on it. Or simply set it in the action as shown above if just needed there.

Comment: Isn't admin prefix routing restricted internally by AuthComponent? That being said, wouldn't admin_login() be inaccessible to a non-authed user? I may be wrong, but that is just what I recall.

Comment: you guys are right I can use same table for admin and user. I'll start with that. Thanks